# https intermittent blocking asset URI - it cannot be found in any file or db

Tags: jquery, wordpress, firefox, https, assets

Per firefox debugging console, https doesn't clear fully intermittent due to blocking http://www.i2wp.org/jquery.js.

It only seems to happen on firefox for some reason.  Chrome and Safari clear every time.

I cannot find this link in any file in this WordPress site document root or in the database.

ie.

```
grep -R "i2wp.org" . (inside document root returns nothing)
```

I made a mysqldump of the db into `dbdump.sql`, then:

```
grep -R "i2wp.org" dbdump.sql (nothing comes back either)
```

This server is running Nginx, php5-fpm, MariaDB, memcached.

I ran freshclam, then clamav scan on full server and found no malware/virus'

Also, my workstation is surely (99.999%) clean too - I run AVG antivirus on MacOSX El Capitan fully updated.

Even stranger, www.i2wp.org and i2wp.org do not resolve to any site, just to a server IP. Whois doesn't show anything interesting either.  Just shows it's registered with eNOM and has privacy protection enabled with privacy protection enabled, and NS1.I2WP.ORG and NS2.I2WP.ORG. i2wp.org resolves to 62.210.146.246 which is a RIPE IP.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: I have clear cookies and cache in firefox as well...

Comment: Found this inspecting the page source when blocking URI happens:  

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.i2wp.org/jquery.js"></script><script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.domain.com/wp-content/plugins/leads//shared//shortcodes/js/spin.min.js'>`

problem is that thjere is no i2wp.org of any sort in spin.min.js anyway.

Comment: Disabled the leads plugin, now I get it like this:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.i2wp.org/jquery.js"></script><link rel='stylesheet' id='frontend.tables-css'  href='https://www.domain.com/wp-content/plugins/pricing-table-by-supsystic/modules/tables/css/frontend.tables.min.css?ver=1.3.6' type='text/css' media='all' />`

It's quite strange.

Answer (score 0):

I met same problem in rebuilding my client's wordpress website, then I found it was a plugin causing the problem, you can put all plugins in one 'hold' folder, take out the plugin one by one, you will find which is the cause. What I found is a plugin called 'Ultimate_VC_Addons'. Upgrading to the latest version resolve the problem. Hope this will help.

BTW:
If you are using cache plugins like w3tc, need 'empty all caches' to reflect the change.